# jest test snapshots fail with last-modified, etag, and other intentionally changing but meaningless values

Tags: jestjs

I can't find an answer to this elsewhere. Using jest for testing, snapshots always fail to match because of changes in the Last-Modified value or the ETag value, or some other such value that may change from run to run without being wrong. A good example less specific than these formal tags would be if one uses a URL parameter to force cache bypassing such as
`<link href="/css/style.min.css?x=123" rel="stylesheet">`
where the value given to x is the timestamp of the file.

Is there a way to make a snapshot test pass in such cases by somehow providing a regexp or and "ignore a line that contains x", or something?

Comment: What are you taking snapshots of? If you're doing snapshot testing you need to be able to control the things you expect to change and don't care about - e.g. treating time as a dependency so you can inject a specific instant.

Comment: What I am doing since I wrote this question is to run the HTML through a few .replace() calls to eliminate the few known variations of the sort I mentioned here. It works, and can be my solution, but I'll leave the question open in case someone knows a more direct way to do this.